# Sentry additional data

Tags: angular, sentry

After I add object in extras ->

Sentry.setExtra('TESTTEST333', { test: [{ test1 : { test2 : {test3: 'a' }}}]});

```
In Sentry under additional date it shows me
{
   test: [
     [Object]
   ]
}
```

How to pass the whole object and display it inside sentry?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your object to a string, with JSON.stringify().

`Sentry.setExtra('TESTTEST333', JSON.stringify({ test: [{ test1 : { test2 : {test3: 'a' }}}]}));`